# How would you upload a audiofile from the client to the backend for audio detection in dialog flow

Tags: node.js, audio, dialogflow-es

Im working on the dialog flow audio detect intent. Im trying to figure out how would you go about uploading a audio file from the client to the backend to be used in dialog flows audio detect. do you upload it to a db and then get the file or is there a way to post the file directly without saving it.

Comment: please find function here `https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/detect.js`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @NikhilSavaliya . I already knew about the client library and which function to use its that i dont which how would you go about sending the audio file to the server.

Comment: from which chat platform you are talking about

Comment: im using an express server to send data to dialogflow client library @NikhilSavaliya